# SQL Server error:948: the database cannot be opened because it version is 896.This Server Support version 782 or earlier?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I recently uninstall my SQL Server 2014 and then reinstalled it. I saved my database `D4SMS` in the `.ldf` and `.mdf` files. Now I cannot attach that database to my SQL Server 2014 version 12.0.5207. I am facing this issue right now in the error message provided in the title and here:

[Here is the error message with additional information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPiCL.png)

Comment: Well, it appears as if you have a SQL Server **2017** database (version 869), and you're trying to attach those to SQL Server 2014 (which only supports up to version 782). This will **NEVER** work- you just plain **cannot do this** - period. No hack, no trick, no workaround.... once a `.mdf` file is version 896, you can attach it **only** to SQL Server **2017** (or newer)

Comment: but in copied my this database files from SQL server 2014 before uninstalling not from  SQL SERVER 2017!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install SqlServer 2017 will definitely resolve your problem as this is version compatibility issue.

Comment: is there any other way, so I can run it back on my  SQL 2014? I copied these files .mdf and .ldf from my SQL server 2014 before uninstalling!

Comment: Yes Saad Shahzad other ways is if you have SQL script with you rather then .mdf files. Other then that there is no way to upgrade that as it may cause you data file corrupted.

Comment: Actually this is the problem with sql database if you have older version it easily open in latest version of sql server but if you have latest version db file it will not be open in older version of sql server.

Comment: Kindly Mark it as answer if it really help you.

Comment: @SaadShahzad: once a `.mdf` file has been "touched" by SQL Server 2017 . then **NO**; there is no way, no trick, no hack, no workaround to get it back into SQL Server 2014. You need to use SQL Server **2017** or newer for this `.mdf` now....

Comment: @MuhammadWaseem my reputation is not enough to vote it Helpful as I am new to this site. anyway, I'll update my version to 2017

Comment: @marc_s I never used SQL Server 2017. Now I'll install  update KB4341265 and will come back Soon!

Comment: @SaadShahzad - well, our choices now are to a) believe that SQL Server is lying, or b) believe that, whether you knew it or not, these database files *have* been attached to a SQL Server 2017 instance. Unfortunately, (b) is far easier to believe than (a)